# My code checking whether a $_REQUEST value is not null is not working. Any ideas?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a block of php to only run if all of my $_GET values are not null.
My code is below:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['name']) 
 || !isset($_REQUEST['number']) 
 || !isset($_REQUEST['section']) 
 || !isset($_REQUEST['email'])){

  //open files and write
  $email_file = fopen("emails","a+");
  $url_file = fopen("urls","a+");
  $courses_file = fopen("courses","a+");
  fwrite($email_file, $_REQUEST['email'] . "\n");
  fwrite($url_file, $url . "\n");
  fwrite($courses_file, $_REQUEST['name'] . " " . $_REQUEST['number'] . " " . $_REQUEST['section'] . "\n");
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working at all. No matter what I pass as a get, nothing gets written to my files. The code works for writing files if I remove the if statement, so I know it's somewhere in my conditional.

Comment: Not null, not set, or empty? All different things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to php.

Comment: I'm passing my values as name=XXXX&number=XXX&section=XXX&email=XXXX. Should I be checking for empty?

Comment: That looks like what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_GET['name']) 
 && !empty($_GET['number']) 
 && !empty($_GET['section']) 
 && !empty($_GET['email'])){

  //open files and write
  file_put_contents('emails.txt', $_GET['email'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

  file_put_contents('urls.txt', $url . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);  // Where does $url come from??? It's not coming from the $_GET params.

  file_put_contents('courses.txt', $_GET['name'] . " " . $_GET['number'] . " " . $_GET['section'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```